# How to resolve DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, axios, domexception

I have an ASP.NET Core with React.js App in Visual Studio. I'm trying to sign into the app after I run it. But I keep getting the error
`DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL    at dispatchXhrRequest (http://localhost:44421/static/js/bundle.js:72972:13)

Here is my Login.js

```
import React from "react"
import { Button, Card, CardContent, TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material"
import { Box } from "@mui/system"
import Center from "./Center"
import useForm from "../hooks/useForm"
import { createAPIEndpoint, ENDPOINTS } from "../api"
import useStateContext from "../hooks/useStateContext"
import { useNavigate } from "react-router"

const getFreshModel = () => ({
    name: '',
    email: ''
})

export default function Login() {

    const { setContext } = useStateContext();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const {
        values,
        errors,
        setErrors,
        handleInputChange
    } = useForm(getFreshModel);

     

    const login = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (validate())
            createAPIEndpoint(ENDPOINTS.participant)
                .post(values)
                .then(res => {
                    setContext({ participantId: res.data.participantId })
                    navigate('/quiz')
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    const validate = () => {
        let temp = {}
        temp.email = (/\S+@\S+\.\S+/).test(values.email) ? "" : "Email is not valid."
        temp.name = values.name !== "" ? "" : "This field is required."
        setErrors(temp)
        return Object.values(temp).every(x => x === "")
    }

    return (
        <Center>
            <Card sx={{ width: 400 }}>
                <CardContent sx={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                    <Typography variant="h3" sx={{ my: 3 }}>
                        Quiz App
                    </Typography>
                    <Box sx={{
                        '& .MuiTextField-root': {
                            m: 1,
                            width: '90%'
                        }
                    }}>
                        <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={login}>
                            <TextField
                                label="Email"
                                name="email"
                                value={values.email}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                variant="outlined"
                                {...(errors.email && { error: true, helperText: errors.email })} />
                            <TextField
                                label="Name"
                                name="name"
                                value={values.name}
                                onChange={handleInputChange}
                                variant="outlined"
                                {...(errors.name && { error: true, helperText: errors.name })} />
                            <Button
                                type="submit"
                                variant="contained"
                                size="large"
                                sx={{ width: '90%' }}>Start</Button>
                        </form>
                    </Box>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </Center>


    )
}
```

And here is my Axios configuration

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5269';

export const ENDPOINTS = {
    participant: 'participant'
}
export const createAPIEndpoint = (endpoint) => {

    const url = BASE_URL + 'api/' + endpoint + '/';
    return {
        fetch: () => axios.get(url),
        fetchById: (id) => axios.get(url + id),
        post: (newRecord) => axios.post(url, newRecord),
        put: (id, updatedRecord) => axios.put(url + id, updatedRecord),
        delete: (id) => axios.delete(url + id),
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `console.log` to log the URLs you are creating in your `createAPIEndpoint` function?

If you do, you might find that they look something like this:

```
http://localhost:5269api/participant/
```

Spot the problem?

You are missing a `/` after the port number `5269` and before the `api`. Without the `/`, the URL is indeed invalid (`5269api` isn't a valid port number), so it's no surprise that you get an "Invalid URL" error.

To fix the problem, add a `/` to the end of the value of `BASE_URL`, or before `api/` in `createAPIEndpoint`.

Comment: Yes, spotted the problem. Thanks